# Read emails from office365 without being asked to grant access via an authorization link

Tags: python, office365

First of all, I apologize if this question was already asked, and I didn't find it.
I am trying to recover emails from office365, received from a specific sender (sender@example.com), using Python. I need to do this on a Linux server, without any user intervention. I mention I can only use the **delegated permissions** approach, as there is no possibility to get access to all mailboxes from the tenant admin.
I managed to recover the emails, but each time the token expires, I am asked to  access a link to grant access to the resources. If I am using the https://localhost redirect uri alternative, I am asked to click on a link, log in azure, which will generate a code in the browser (which will also not help at all, as long as I must click on that link).

Sorry if I am not clear enough, and please let me know what other details you need. It's my first time I ask a question here.

Thank you for your support!

I wrote the code, but I am still asked to click on the links

Comment: It's unlikely that you can do this without admin access. The whole point of the delegated permissions approach is to make sure the user who's delegating permissions approves the access.

Comment: Can you please recommend an alternative to this approach? Is there a way to do this without human intervention and without using application permissions?